# Trouble getting my server to respond back to client | Python | Sockets

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, server, client-server, python-sockets

I'm trying to repurpose this script, I want the server to send messages to my client, and I want the client to be the one that 'reaches out' and makes the connection. As you can see, with the script I have, **the client is the one reaching out but it's the one that can send the messages to the server**. I've tried looking at other scripts, moving the send and handle function around, but I feel like my inexperience with sockets got me stumped. Any help would be appreicated.

Server:

```
import socket 
import threading

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5430
SERVER = '192.110.100.189' # socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) 
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = '!END'

# defines the type of connection
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f'[NEW CONNECTIONS] {addr} connected')

    connected = True
    while connected:
        # the header variable here acts as a protocol to give us an idea of how many bytes are being sent
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                break
            
            print(f'{addr} | {msg}')

            conn.send('msg recieved'.encode(FORMAT))

    conn.close()

def start(): 
    server.listen()
    print(f'[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}')
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept() 

        thread = threading.Thread(target = handle_client, args = (conn, addr))
        thread.start()

        print(f'[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}')

print('[STARTNG] Server is starting')
start()
```

Client:

```
import socket

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5430
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = '!END' 
SERVER = '192.110.100.189'
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)

    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))

    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)

while True:
    enter = input('CLIENT - ')
    send(enter)

    if enter == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
        break
```

Comment: If you want the server to send messages and the client to receive them then after the server returns from the `server.accept()` it should start sending messages, in your case in `handle_client()`. And the client of course should return from `client.connect()` and prepare to receive the server messages by calling `client.recv()`. This is the broad outline of what you seem to want.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk loooooool I threw some pieces of code together and somehow it worked. Thank youuuuuuuuuu!

Comment: I knew you had it in you :)